# Highchart is not getting populated using external json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, highcharts

I am trying to reload the data for a `Highcharts` chart via `JSON`.
I have a `HTML` file, when I hard code the `categories` and `series` in HTML `Highchart` is working, but when I am trying to load the data using `Json` its not working.

**HTML file**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="C:\Users\Global Soft\Desktop\HighChart\js\highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'line',
                    marginRight: 130,
                    marginBottom: 25
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Revenue vs. Overhead',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Json Example',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: []
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Amount'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                            this.x +': '+ this.y;
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: 100,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: []
            }
            
            $.getJSON("C:\Users\Global Soft\Desktop\HighChart\zmy design\data.json", function(json) {
                options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
                options.series[0] = json[1];
                options.series[1] = json[2];
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });
        });
        </script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**data.json**

```html
[{
    "name": "Month",
    "data": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
}, {
    "name": "Revenue",
    "data": [23987, 24784, 25899, 25569, 25897, 25668, 24114, 23899, 24987, 25111, 25899, 23221]
}, {
    "name": "Overhead",
    "data": [21990, 22365, 21987, 22369, 22558, 22987, 23521, 23003, 22756, 23112, 22987, 22897]
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

the problem with your code is you are loading js files twice and also make sure that your file path is correct. try this :

```js
     $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'line',
                    marginRight: 130,
                    marginBottom: 25
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Revenue vs. Overhead',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Json Example',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: []
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Amount'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                            this.x +': '+ this.y;
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: 100,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: []
            }
            
            $.getJSON("https://googledrive.com/host/0B3_2aPWXzW1LMGZmblNBcVBzcjg", function(json) {//https is aaddress for your file
                options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
                options.series[0] = json[1];
                options.series[1] = json[2];
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
   
        </script>
      
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry bro it is Not Working

Comment: have you changed the file path as per yours.

Comment: Yes . I changed it, though its not working help me bro

Comment: @Mackan need your help

Comment: @varun   see the update answer and if any problem let me know.

Comment: your answer is working but when I am giving my path like:"C:\Users\Global Soft\Desktop\HighChart\zmy design\data.json" its not working why??

Comment: do console.log (json) inside $.getJSON and see what id gives.make sure you have given correct path.

Comment: This is what I am getting --'Uncaught Highcharts error #16: www.highcharts.com/errors/16
jquery.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/UsersGlobal%20SoftDesktopHighChartzmy%20designdata.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.'

Comment: read about the cross origin or try with putting the data.json file in your project directory.

Comment: data.json is in my project directory

Comment: then instead of c:file ...... use your project path...like myproject\folder\data.json