# How to return JSON data form controller to jsp in MVC

Tags: java, javascript, json, jsp

I'm trying to retrieve the data from database and return it as a JSON from controller so that I can display highchart of that data in jsp.
Initially I'm trying to alert the JSON data in alert() to check wether data is coming or not. **json which I am returning from controller is not populated in alert**. Can anybody help me with this?

**ReportModel.java**

```html
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ReportModel {
 int year;
 int population;
 
 public int getYear() {
  return year;
 }
 public void setYear(int year) {
  this.year = year;
 }
 public int getPopulation() {
  return population;
 }
 public void setPopulation(int population) {
  this.population = population;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "reportModel [year=" + year + ", population=" + population + "]";
 }
      
   }
```

**ReportDao**

```html
@Repository
public class ReportDao {
 


 @Autowired
 private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
 
 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
 @Autowired
 private SimpleJdbcTemplate simpleJdbcTemplate;
 

 public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
  this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
 }




 public void setSimpleJdbcTemplate(SimpleJdbcTemplate simpleJdbcTemplate) {
  this.simpleJdbcTemplate = simpleJdbcTemplate;
 }
 
 //method to retrieve the data from population table
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public List<ReportModel> getReport() {
  final String reportQuery = "SELECT year, population from population";
   List<ReportModel> report = new ArrayList<ReportModel>();

   report = jdbcTemplate.query(
    reportQuery, new RowMapper<ReportModel>() {

     public ReportModel mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)
       throws SQLException {

      ReportModel model = new ReportModel();
      model.setYear(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("year")));
      model.setPopulation(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("population")));
      

      return model;
     }

    });
  
  return  report ;
 }
}
```

**ReportImpl**

```html
@Service
public class ReportImpl {
 
 @Autowired
 ReportDao reportDao; 
 private static final org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReportDao.class);
  
      public void setReportDao(ReportDao reportDao) {
  this.reportDao = reportDao;
 }
 
 public List<ReportModel> getReportModels() {
  return reportDao.getReport();
 }  

}
```

**ReportController**

```html
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/reportController")
public class ReportController {
 
 @Autowired
 ReportImpl reportImpl;
 
 public void setReportImpl(ReportImpl reportImpl) {
  this.reportImpl = reportImpl;
 }

 public ReportController() {
  super();
  System.out.println("inside Reportconstructor"); 
  }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/getreport", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 @ResponseBody
  public Object getReportData()
    {
  System.out.println("inside report controller : get Report");
  List<ReportModel> reportModel =  reportImpl.getReportModels();
  Object json = null;
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
     
     //display to console
     json = objectMapper.readValue(
          objectMapper.writeValueAsString(reportModel), Object.class);
    
    }catch(JsonGenerationException e)
    {
     e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    
    return json;
   
 
    }
}
```

**report.jsp**

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        alert("The button is clicked.");
        
        
        <!--ajax call-->
        $.ajax({
      type : "GET",
      url : '/dispatcherServlet/ReportController/getReportData',
      dataType : "json",
         contentType: "application/json",
         crossDomain:true,
      success : function(data) {
       //console.log(data);
       //alert(success);
       for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
        {
         alert(data[i].name);
        }
      }
       
       error : function(data) {
        alert(data);
        }
        });
        <!--ajax call-->
        
        
    });
});

</script>
    </head>
  </html>
```

Comment: "I dont know what is wrong with my code." Are you getting an exception? Any error, CPU is on fire? What is happening? Did you debug the code?

Comment: The problem is with jsp the json which I am returning from controller to jsp. I am trying to alert alert(data); but no out put. no error

Comment: Check the request & response data in your browser; See if you are receiving the value from the server, if not then debug your server side code; if yes then issue with your client side code;

Comment: Hi, @Varun, did the below shared answer worked

Comment: @rinilnath Please look at bellow questions it may help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30251868/highchart-is-not-getting-populated-using-external-json-data
High chart is not getting populated
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30370855/high-chart-is-not-getting-populated
How to display Multiple Highchart on a single page
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30346336/how-to-display-multiple-highchart-in-single-page

Comment: That is true I was using the wrong URL mapping.
In Ajax call I was using.
url : '/dispatcherServlet/ReportController/getReportData'

My controller has url mapping.
@RequestMapping(value = "/getreport", method = RequestMethod.GET)

Comment: My search is not for high charts, but i have one question, how did you manage Json object passing to JSP with valid header, I am trying to get JSON object in similar fashion but got 406- response code

Answer (score 0):

INCORRECT url : '/dispatcherServlet/ReportController/getReportData',

CORRECT url : '/dispatcherServlet/ReportController/getreport'

Issue is with your request mapping.